# How to exit while(1) loop after sometime in C?

Tags: c, while-loop

I am making a program in which I am getting data from a serial device. The problem which I am facing is that the device gives me the wrong data until I run while(1) and then read the data. So I thought of running a for loop for 100000 times and then reading the data but still it was giving wrong data. I can only use while(1). So is there anyway I can stop while(1) after sometime like 7-10sec.?
please help,thanks.!!

Comment: Have you aware of signals?

Comment: Looks like you're in need for [`sleep()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep)

Comment: "I can only use while(1)" - why?

Comment: If you need a delay, use proper APIs designed for that purpose.

Comment: Use `break` to exit from an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will help.

```
int i=0;
while(1){
   // do your work.
   if ( i == 100 ) break; // for an example.
   i++;
}
printf("After While\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary for your `while` loop to iterate on `1`? Perhaps you could loop on `time(NULL)` instead, for example:

```
time_t t = time(NULL) + 10;
while (time(NULL) < t) {
    /* ... */
}
```

This is not exactly precise; The loop could run for anything between 9 seconds and 10 seconds, perhaps even longer depending on how saturated your CPU usage is by other tasks. It doesn't look like you're looking for anything precise, however, and this should give you some idea...

If for whatever silly reason you must use `while (1)`, then you can use this idea together with `if` and `break` like so:

```
time_t t = time(NULL) + 10;
while (1) {
    if (time(NULL) >= t) {
        break;
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To exit the loop you have to use `break` statement.

```
while(1)  
{
    //your code...
    sleep(7);//to sleep for 7 seconds
    break;//jumps out of the loop after 7 seconds of delay
}
```

Comment: `sleep` doesn't seem suitable because that function blocks until the period of time has elapsed, meaning that the loop can't perform any work in the mean time. I doubt the OP wants a loop that does nothing.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    time_t end  = time(NULL) + 7; //7s

    while (1) {

        //your code...
        printf("running...\n");

        if (time(NULL) >= end) {
            break;
        }

        //your code..
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
while(1) {
   delay(10000); //To delay for 10 seconds.
   break;
}
```

If you can't use delay() then probably use some loop to get significant amount of time delay and thereafter break the loop.

Comment: I'm not sure what `delay` is, but if it's anything like `sleep` (which it seems like it will be) it doesn't seem suitable because that function will block until the period of time has elapsed, meaning that the loop can't perform any work in the mean time. I doubt the OP wants a loop that does nothing.